# PHP If statements not working

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
    if ($username == "" || $pass == "" || $emailad==""|| $fname=="")
{  
    $msg = "Not all fields were entered"; 
}else
{
    if(uniqueUser($username,$emailad))
    {
        $msg="The username or email already exists";
    }else
    { 
        insertIntoDB($fname,$emailad,$username,$pass);
        $msg="The user has been inserted";

    }

}
    echo $msg;
```

this will be used to insert a new user into my db. However my problem is if I am to add a non existing user into it, the program will tell me that the username already exists BUT it will insert the new account if its not in the database. Therefore the program works fine in terms of insertion depending upon if the user exists in the database or not. The problem is the message display for me because I will never know if the user is already in the database or not since no matter how I rewrite this piece of code, a non existent user insertion will result in the wrong message being displayed. This is because the code will run the if statements, insert the new user....and run again displaying the message that it already exists. Could anybody explain why this happens?

Unique user function:

```
function uniqueUser($usern,$eml)
{
$query = "SELECT S.username,S.email FROM tbl_user S WHERE S.username='$usern' OR        S.email='$eml'";
return mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query));
}
```

Comment: why is this code  being called twice then?

Comment: Your script is being called twice - sometimes this is because of a URL rewrite being done by the web server. Check your web logs to see if you have two requests for every one you expect.

Comment: could it be you did something wrong with the `uniqueUser` function?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want to echo the message? Add `echo` before the `$msg` in the `if` statement.

```
if(uniqueUser($username,$emailad))
{
    echo $msg="The username or email already exists";
}else
{ 
    insertIntoDB($fname,$emailad,$username,$pass);
    $msg="The user has been inserted";
    echo $msg;
}
```

If the user exists then the "The username or email already exists" message is output. If the user does not exist then it will be inserted and the "The user has been inserted" message output.

Comment: just curious, why would you assign the string to the variable when you could just echo it directly?

Comment: I did that because I wanted to echo it at the end of the whole if statement.

Comment: @user1329178, actually, i was asking the michael, but in your case, if that is what you're trying to do, shouldn't the echo statement put outside?
and also, read my comment on your original question as well,

Comment: @that_guy, it was quicker for me to just add an `echo` than to add it and delete `$msg`.

Comment: @user1329178 Then you need to place your `echo $msg;` after the last closing `}` of the last else branch.

Comment: Yeah it should have been put outside, I'm sorry. But even then the code does not work for some reason, I don't understand why it reruns the if statement after it has inserted which means that if you enter a new one it will always say that its already there

Comment: Post the whole page of your code then. You might have something set up to re-run the statement again. Also, are you using mod_rewrite? That can cause each page to load twice.

Comment: @MichaelRushton, lol

to OP, i suspect the problem lies with your `uniqueUser` function, maybe you can try posting it here?

Comment: @MichaelRushton Nope mod_rewrite was never used

Answer (score 1):

TRY this

```
if ($username == "" || $pass == "" || $emailad==""|| $fname=="")
{  
    $msg = "Not all fields were entered"; 
}
else if(uniqueUser($username,$emailad))
{
    $msg="The username or email already exists";
}
else
{ 
    insertIntoDB($fname,$emailad,$username,$pass);
    $msg="The user has been inserted";
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: I apologize for haivng the echo message inside, original post has been editted

Answer (score 0):

Heres the algorithm that i can suggest:

1. Check if the fields are empty
2. Check if the user already exists in the database ( in this case, you need to select the base for specific field for example the email field or username field.
3. Success, insert the data to the database if user doesnt exist.

So here is the code:

```
    <?php

/**
 * @author MESMERiZE
 * @copyright 2012
 */

if (empty($username) || empty($pass) || empty($pass) || empty($fname))
{  
        $msg = "Not all fields were entered"; 
}else
{
    // FALSE if exists TRUE if doesnt exist
    if(uniqueUser($username,$emailad) == FALSE)
    {
        $msg="The username or email already exists";

    }else
    { 
        insertIntoDB($fname,$emailad,$username,$pass);
        $msg="The user has been inserted";
        echo $msg;
    }

}

?>
```

Edit your uniqueUser function to:

```
function userExists($usern, $eml)
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user S WHERE S.username="' . $usern .
        '" OR S.email="' . $eml . '"';
    $q = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a run now, will get back to you in a minute. Thank you for your help

Comment: Your welcome let me know if it works. Also kindly share the code for uniqueUser function so we can see the problem behind it.

Comment: The problem still persists sadly